# Understanding question to the CNP-part by Fermat?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is asked

> *Proof $\forall x $: $x^2$ isn't a congruent number*

*Fermat proved
the first key theorem on this topic, that $1$ is not a congruent number.  He also noted that this implied that there are no rational $(x,y)$ with
$x,y\neq 0$ such that $x^4+y^4=1$.*

Steps:

*$1)$ show that $1$ isn't a congruent number*

*this is done*

*$2)$ than use that $x^4+y^4=z^2$ has no solution in $\Bbb N$*

*As $1\in\Bbb N$, we can say that for $x^4+y^4=1$ there aren't any $(x,y)\in \Bbb N$.*

My first problem is why does it suffices to show that $1$ isn't congruent number.

And , I thought we would talk about rational numbers and not natural, I mean yes,as $\Bbb N \subset \Bbb Q$ therefore if $(x,y)\in \Bbb N$ so $(x,y)\in \Bbb Q$ , but as we're talking about congruent numbers, don't we need all rational numbers and not just a part of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [congruent number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number), by definition, is a positive integer that is the area of a right triangle with three rational number sides.
If the sides are $a,b,c$, then the area is $ab/2$. Now, if we scale this triangle by a rational number $x$, then the area is scaled by $x^2$. Since also
every rational number can be multiplied by a suitable rational square to
become a square-free integer, we have the following implication:
if $1$ is not congruent, then also $x^2$ is not congruent for all positiv integers $x$. So you only need Fermat to prove that $1$ is not a congruent number.